# All new actions on controller are coming up 404 in my existing controller and new ones

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

All of a sudden, new actions on all my controllers are coming up with 404 errors.

The actions that were already there work fine.  For instance this controller method works:

```
public ActionResult AddItem() 
{
   return View();
}
```

But this one does not:

```
public ActionResult Bob()
{
   return View();
}
```

Both Views/Tools/AddItem.aspx and Views/Tools/Bob.aspx exist and the global.asax default route remains unchanged.

I've tried closing VS2010 and re-opening to no avail.

If I try to create a new controller and make a basic ActionResult like above, it fails with a 404 too.

Has this happened to anyone else before?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have recompiled your project and/or not deployed the udpated dll to your server.

Comment: I've cleaned/rebuilt/open-closed.  Created new controllers.  It's running locally and I have stopped and restarted Cassini a billion times.  Puzzling.